# julia returning array results in nothing

Tags: julia

I have the following code,

```
function sample_gaussian(n; mean=0., variance=0.01)
  # n samples from standard gaussian
  x = randn(n);
  z = sqrt(variance) .* x .+ mean;
  return z;
end
```

When I try to call `z = sample_gaussian(100)` and print it, I get that z is nothing. Can anyone help to explain please?

Comment: works for me (try it in a new REPL session). my best guess is that you have some old definition of `sample_gaussian` that you are not updating correctly

Comment: That seemed to be the problem! Just an additional question, how is the .* different from * in array manipulation?

Comment: `*` is matrix multiplication. `.*` is element wise

Comment: If you reuse the `x` vector like this, `x .= sqrt(variance) .* x .+ mean`, you save memory and will get a speedup. `.=` means that you overwrite `x` in memory, which is ok here.

Comment: Just to note that efficient sampling from many well-known distributions is implemented by [Distributions](https://github.com/JuliaStats/Distributions.jl)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> works for me (try it in a new REPL session). my best guess is that you have some old definition of sample_gaussian that you are not updating correctly – David Varela Jan 9 at 2:38